# Configuring USB-Souncard for Microphone

Tags: sound, microphone, soundcard, headset

I just recently installed Ubuntu alongside Windows 10 and tried using my Headset.
The sound works fine, however the microphone doesn't work at all. More specifically it isn't even detected (soundcard is, but microphone isn't). My Headset Connects to the Soundcard via a single 3.5 Jack. I can't wrap my head around on what to do. I though that maybe setting the Sound-Card as a Stereo Duplex in pavucontrol would work, but the only things I can select there are different output options (so maybe creating a new profile would help, but then again how do I do that?).

I am really new to Linux in generell so I'd appreciate every little bit of help I can get. 
The soundcard that I am using is the HyperX Amp. Headset works fine on Windows 10.